# How can I add parameters to the Yahoo MRSS feed generated by Kaltura KMC?

Tags: kaltura

I'm using the Kaltura KMC to generate a Yahoo! MRSS feed ([per the info here](http://cdnknowledge.kaltura.com//sites/default/files/Kaltura%20Content%20Syndication.pdf)).

The feed it creates looks like this:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
  <channel>
    <title>yahoo mrss feed</title>
    <link>http://xxxx.com</link>
    <description></description>
    <item>
      <title>My Dog Clip</title>
      <link>http://xxxx.com?videoid=0_udwmgjec</link>
      <media:content url="http://xxxx.com/p/100/sp/10000/serveFlavor/flavorId/0_e5h0z4cf">
        <media:title>My Dog Clip</media:title>
        <media:description>Here is a clip of the dog playing!</media:description>
        <media:keywords>dog clip</media:keywords>
        <media:thumbnail url="http://xxxx.com/p/100/sp/10000/thumbnail/entry_id/0_udwmgjec/version/100002"></media:thumbnail>
        <media:category scheme="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/category_schema">Entertainment &amp; TV</media:category>
        <media:player url="http://xxxx.com/kwidget/wid/_100/entry_id/0_udwmgjec/ui_conf_id/48501"></media:player>
        <media:rating scheme="urn:simple"></media:rating>
      </media:content>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

This is pretty good, but I see two things that need adjusting:

1. On the `<media:content>` tag, I'd like to add the `type` parameter, indicating the MIME type. Is there a way to do this through the KMC interface?
2. I'd like to change the default size of the thumbnail it generates (and also add the image suffix, like `.jpg`, to the end of the URL). Is there an option for that in the KMC?

It seems like I might end up needing to use the API to build the MRSS feed myself on the fly (pulling the video data from Kaltura via the API). What do you think?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dynamic MRSS
To upload your owned XSD, and modify the original.

Comment: Thanks. With the free open-source KMC, the option to use a custom XSD isn't available. However, it is on my paid KMC account.